# in send mail from is not working in django

Tags: python, django, email

i am trying to send the mail in django. mail is going properly but mail is going by EMAIL_HOST_USER. Want to send the mail using from i.e. from some other email address.

settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST ='smtp.gmail.com' 
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'you@everycrave.me' 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*********' 
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

in view:

```
text="hi this is test mail"
send_mail('Codeville Signup', text.decode(), 'gaurav@everycrave.me', ['manish@everycrave.me', 'jagat@everycrave.me'], fail_silently=False)
```

i want to send the mail from "gaurav@everycrave.me" but mail is getting sent by "you@everycrave.me"
How can i overcome this problem. And i dont want to change EMAIL_HOST_USER mail address.
Guide me through this

Comment: might be related to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590518/emailbackend-for-sending-email-through-multiple-smtp-in-django

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [EmailBackend for sending email through multiple SMTP in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590518/emailbackend-for-sending-email-through-multiple-smtp-in-django) this question or

in your view you have to write this code, from where you are sending the email.

```
from django.core.mail import get_connection, send_mail
from django.core.mail.message import EmailMessage
#TODO: Insert clever settings mechanism
my_host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
my_port = 587
my_username = 'your email address'
my_password = 'password'
my_use_tls = True
connection = get_connection(host=my_host, 
                            port=my_port, 
                            username=my_username, 
                            password=my_password, 
                            user_tls=my_use_tls) 

EmailMessage('Test subject', 'test message', 'from_email', ['to'], connection = connection).send(fail_silently=False)
```

Check this.